# vb.net report viewer multiple reports

Tags: vb.net, reportviewer, report-viewer2010

Within vb.net is there a way I can dynamically create multiple reports using the same rdlc but with different SQL statements.

So in essence I want to write a loop that will open the same report multiple times within the viewer which will end up having many pages..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently not, I ended up creating a new report and using the list box tool.